# When i click on chrome extension it should run server.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome-extension, android-manifest

I have made a website that uses chatGPT to reply mail. Now I want to make extensions out of it, where when the user paste their mails it generates the reply in a popup, then the user can copy from that. Now when I run npm commands for client and server my website is working perfectly, but I don't know how to run it when the user clicks on extension?

here is the manifest.json:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "ChatGPT Email Assistant",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "An email assistant that uses the ChatGPT language model",
    "permissions": [
      "activeTab",
      "storage",
      "http://localhost:5000"
    ],
    "browser_action": {
      "default_popup": "./client/index.html"
    }

  }
```

here is server.js:

```
import express from 'express';
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';
import cors from 'cors';
import { Configuration, OpenAIApi } from 'openai';
dotenv.config();
const configuration = new Configuration({
  apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY
  
});
const openai = new OpenAIApi(configuration);
const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).send({
    message: 'Hello From Codex!'
  })
})
app.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const prompt = req.body.prompt;
      const response = await openai.createCompletion({
        model: "text-davinci-003",
        prompt: `Reply this email +${prompt}`,
        temperature: 0, 
        max_tokens: 3000, 
        top_p: 1,
        frequency_penalty: 0.5,
        presence_penalty: 0,
      });
      res.status(200).send({
        bot: response.data.choices[0].text,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error)
      res.status(500).send(error || 'Something went wrong');
    }
  })
  app.listen(5000, () => console.log('AI server started on http://localhost:5000'))
```

script.js:

```
import bot from "./assets/bot.svg";
import user from "./assets/user.svg";

const form = document.querySelector("form");
const chatContainer = document.querySelector("#chat_container");
let loadInterval;
function loader(element) {
  element.textContent = "";
  loadInterval = setInterval(() => {
    element.textContent += ".";
    if (element.textContent === "....") {
      element.textContent = "";
    }
  }, 300);
}
function typeText(element, text) {
  let index = 0;
  let interval = setInterval(() => {
    if (index < text.length) {
      element.innerHTML += text.charAt(index);
      index++;
    } else {
      clearInterval(interval);
    }
  }, 20);
}
function generateUniqueId() {
  const timestamp = Date.now();
  const randomNumber = Math.random();
  const hexadecimalString = randomNumber.toString(16);
  return `id-${timestamp}-${hexadecimalString}`;
}
function chatStripe(isAi, value, uniqueId) {
  return `
      <div class="wrapper ${isAi && "ai"}">
          <div class="chat">
              <div class="profile">
                  <img 
                    src=${isAi ? bot : user} 
                    alt="${isAi ? "bot" : "user"}" 
                  />
              </div>
              <div class="message" id=${uniqueId}>${value}</div>
          </div>
      </div>
  `;
}
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const data = new FormData(form);
  // to clear the textarea input
  form.reset();
  form.classList.add('formdisplay');
  // bot's chatstripe
  const uniqueId = generateUniqueId();
  chatContainer.innerHTML += chatStripe(true, " ", uniqueId);
  // to focus scroll to the bottom
  chatContainer.scrollTop = chatContainer.scrollHeight;
  const messageDiv = document.getElementById(uniqueId);
  // messageDiv.innerHTML = "..."
  loader(messageDiv);
  //here we are going to fetch data
  const response = await fetch("http://localhost:5000", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      prompt: data.get("prompt"),
    }),
  });
  clearInterval(loadInterval);
  messageDiv.innerHTML = "";
  if (response.ok) {
    const data = await response.json();
    const parsedData = data.bot.trim();
    // console.log(parsedData);
    typeText(messageDiv, parsedData);
  } else {
    const err = await response.text();
    messageDiv.innerHTML = " Oops! Something went wrong.";
    alert(err);
  }
};

form.addEventListener("submit", handleSubmit);
form.addEventListener("keyup", (e) => {
  if (e.keyCode === 13) {
    handleSubmit(e);
  }
});
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "script.js"});
});
```

Now when click on extension, a popup window should open then after when user paste their mail text as soon I enter it should give the AI generated reply.

Comment: The path in default_popup should be relative to manifest.json in the build (dist) directory, which you can verify in a file manager. If it's the same directory there should be no path at all, just index.html. Note that the popup is a separate window so it has its own separate devtools: right-click inside the popup and select "inspect" in the menu.

Comment: @SujansinhThakor - On on unrelated note: Who is the target audience for your website? People who work in customer support?

Comment: @ThomasMueller I making this project out of curiosity, i had an idea about it so I'm just making it, there no targeted audience as of now, just for learning.